# Play Framework await() makes the application act wierd

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework-1.x

I am having some strange trouble with the method await(Future future) of the Controller.

Whenever I add an await line anywhere in my code, some GenericModels which have nothing to do with where I placed await, start loading incorrectly and I can not access to any of their attributes.

The wierdest thing is that if I change something in another completely different java file anywhere in the project, play will try to recompile I guess and in that moment it starts working perfectly, until I clean tmp again.

Comment: Could you show related part of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use await in a controller it does bytecode enhancement to break a single method into two threads.  This is pretty cool, but definitely one of the 'black magic' tricks of Play1.  But, this is one place where Play often acts weird and requires a restart (or as you found, some code changing) - the other place it can act strange is when you change a Model class.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/asynchronous#SuspendingHTTPrequests

> To make it easier to deal with asynchronous code we have introduced
>   continuations. Continuations allow your code to be suspended and
>   resumed transparently. So you write your code in a very imperative
>   way, as:
>
> public static void computeSomething() {
>        Promise delayedResult = veryLongComputation(…);
>        String result = await(delayedResult);
>        render(result); }
>
> In fact here, your code will be executed in 2 steps, in 2 different hreads. But as you see it, it’s very
>   transparent for your application code.
>
> Using await(…) and continuations, you could write a loop:

```
 public static void loopWithoutBlocking() {
     for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) { 
          Logger.info(i);
          await("1s");
     }
     renderText("Loop finished"); }
```

> And using only 1 thread (which is the default in development mode) to process requests, Play is able to
>   run concurrently these loops for several requests at the same time.

---

To respond to your comment:

```
 public static void generatePDF(Long reportId) {
    Promise<InputStream> pdf = new ReportAsPDFJob(report).now();
    InputStream pdfStream = await(pdf);
    renderBinary(pdfStream);
```

and ReportAsPDFJob is simply a play Job class with doJobWithResult overridden - so it returns the object.  See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/jobs for more on jobs.

Calling `job.now()` returns a future/promise, which you can use like this: `await(job.now())`

Comment: Great, I came up with the same conclusion, and I could have not described it better than play's black magic. Your workaround seems interesting, however if I am waiting here for an object to be ready, how can I control that? await(1s) until promiseObject.isDone?

Comment: if you want to wait on something to return, then use Job with result.  i'll update the answer.

Comment: hope that edit helps.  but the main issue in this question is how play  auto-recompilation happens when you are developing.  i would say, it just sometimes breaks - knowing on what/why just helps you know when you need to restart play.

Comment: Yup, that  await(promiseTaskResult); line is the one when messing with my project, so I have to avoid using it. I ended up using the older, deprecated and not so cool waitFor(). However this did help me a lot, thank you.